# Why does every JS object have one undefined property

Tags: javascript, console, undefined, console.log

```
let obj = {a:'a',b:'b'};
for (let p in obj){
   console.log(p);
}
```

Output:

```
a 
b
undefined
```

What's up with the undefined property?

Comment: Thats not property its `return of function` that `developer tools` prints

Comment: Well do I feel dumb right now. If you repost this as an answer I can accept it

Comment: no problem.. no question is dumb untill you know the answer, also a fun fact developer tools prints the returned response in case of AJAX, even if you have consoled it outside of callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a property, it's the ***return of function*** that ***developer tools*** prints.

Example:

```
console.logger = function(p){
           console.log(p);
           return "logged"
      }
var obj = {a:'a',b:'b'};
for (var p in obj){
   console.logger(p);
}

a          // logs the property
b          // logs the property
"logged"   // logs the return of logger function, undefined in case nothing's returned
```